# PowerShell script export SQL to CSV add delimiter

Tags: powershell

I'm doing a script to export data from a SQL Server database. I want to output a .csv file with as delimiter ";".

Here is my script:

```
#Variable to hold variable  
$SQLServer = "SERVEUR"  
$SQLDBName = "TOTO"  
$uid ="PS"  
$pwd = "password123"   
$delimiter = ";"

#SQL Query  
$SqlQuery = "SELECT * from $SQLDBName.dbo.SAGE_TO_PRESTASHOP;"  
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection  
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True;"  
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand  
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery  
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection  
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter  
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd   
#Creating Dataset  
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet  
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)  
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Out-File "E:\EXPORTS\export.csv"
```

Comment: `Out-File` -> `Export-Csv -Delimiter ';'`

Comment: [`Export-Csv` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6). Note the `-Delimiter` parameter.

Comment: [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6) has a `delimiter` parameter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace your bottom line with this:

```
$DataSet.Tables[0] | export-csv -Delimiter $delimiter -Path "E:\EXPORTS\export.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```